# How to create JPEG image on iOS from scratch

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing

I'm trying to create an objective C classe for my iPad application which can convert a powerpoint file to a jpeg file.
Accordingly i've to read into the pptx format to see how the file is structured and create an image, from scratch, in which i can say this element goes there, this one here, this text there.

But actually i've no idea how to do this, if the best way is to use a already existing framework in iOS or an additional library?

Thanks to everyone ;)

Bye

Comment: This question is too broad. Which part are you having trouble with - reading the pptx file, rendering it, or creating an image?

Comment: I can already read within the pptx file and inside xml files as well, the question is how can i draw this content as it is in the real powerpoint file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to visualize elements is, to me, OpenGL ES. You can use mobile GPU to visualize then there is [CIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for managing image.

Comment: He just wants to render the PPT into an image, using OpenGL just adds complexity in this case.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to convert the pptx file to image to apply a texture to an openGL shape

Comment: Even in that case you’re going to render the image using Quartz and then just upload it as a texture to the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/), the drawing engine used as the main workhorse for 2D graphics on iOS. It gives you all the primitives for drawing shapes, fills, text and other objects you need to render the presentation.